# Modelling if elif else conditions as MIP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, logical-constraints

I have 4 variables. Xl6, Xs6, Pl6, Ps6. I have a constant C as well.

Xl6 and Xs6 are binary whereas Pl6 and Ps6 are integers. Also, all variables can take only positive values.

I have to implement following constraints in an MIP:

```
If Xl6 == 0 then Pl6 == 0 else Pl6 > 0
If Xs6 == 0 then Ps6 == 0 else Ps6 > 0
```

Another set of if-else constraints are:

```
if Xl6 == 1 and Xs6 == 1 then Pl6 + Ps6 >= C
elif Xl6 == 1 and Xs6 == 0 then Pl6 >= C
elif Xl6 == 0 and Xs6 == 1 then Ps6 >= C
```

Also, we have another constraint that `Xl6 and Xs6 both can't be zero at the same time`. This has been implemented as `Xl6 + Xs6 >= 1`.

How can we formulate above set of conditions as linear constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part, let $Ul6$ and $Us6$ be upper bounds on $Pl6$ and $Ps6$, respectively, and impose linear constraints:
\begin{align}
Xl6 \le Pl6 &\le Ul6 Xl6 \\
Xs6 \le Ps6 &\le Us6 Xs6
\end{align}
For the second part:
\begin{align}
Pl6 + Ps6 &\ge C(Xl6 + Xs6 - 1) \\
Pl6 &\ge C(Xl6 - Xs6) \\
Ps6 &\ge C(Xs6 - Xl6)
\end{align}

Comment: Hi @RobPratt, Do you mean $Ul6$ and $Us6$ are upper bounds of $Pl6$ and $Ps6$ respectively? since $Xl6$ and $Xs6$ are already binary.

Comment: @mufassir Yes, corrected.

Answer (score 4):

$ \sigma Xl6 \le Pl6 \le UXl6 $
$ \sigma Xs6 \le Ps6 \le UXs6 $
$\sigma$ is very small nonnegative number (even 1 as Prof Rubin suggested since PPl/Ps are integers) & $U$($ \gt$ C) is upper bound for Pl & Ps

$C(Xl6+Xs6 -1) + U(Xl6+Xs6-2) \le Pl6 + Ps6$
$CXl6 - U(Xl6+2Xls6-1)\le Pl6$
$CXs6 - U(2Xl6+Xls6-1)\le Ps6$

$ 1 \le Xl6 + Xs6$ as you've already

If both integer vars can take positive values only then 2nd bunch of constraints can be replaced by
$CXl6 \le Pl6$
$CXs6 \le Ps6$

Comment: Since the $P$ variables are integers, $\sigma=1$ will work. The second group of constraints needs some corrections. For instance, if $Xl6=0$ and $Xs6=1,$ the middle constraint in the second group forces $Pl6\ge C$ which is not part of what was requested.

Comment: copy-pasting error, corrected it.

Comment: this is make Pl/Ps free (instead of $\ge 0$) if Xs/Xl = 1

Comment: Your final two constraints are too strong when both $X$ variables are $1$.

Comment: So you mean, if both are 1, then possible the Ps individually may be smaller than C? But if either Xs are 1, the corresponding Ps are greater then C.

Comment: If both $X$ variables are $1$, only the *sum* of the $P$ variables must be $\ge C$, but your constraints force *each* $P$ variable to be $\ge C$.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that `pl6` is a non-negative integer.  (tell me if it holds).
For `Xl==0 then Pl6 ==0` you can have :

`Pl6<= Xl6`

This tells you that if Xl6 = 0 : Pl6<= 0 and since it takes >=0 values , it has to be 0.

`Pl6>= Xl6/M` where M is a really big integer.
Now if Xl6==1  Pl6>1/M --> Pl6 >0

---

For the second type of contraint:

```
Pl6 + Ps6 >= C(Xl6 + Xs6 - 1)
```

Notice that if and only if `Xl6 = Xs6 = 1` the right-hand will be exactly C.
If both are 0 it will be negative (and therefore do nothing) , and if one of them is 1 if will be 0.

(Everything I said holds if P's are non-negative)

Comment: yes, all variables are positive.

Comment: Hey, thank you for attempting this. I see few issues here. In part 1, Pl6<=Xl6 will restrict Pl6 to be 1 or 0 only in case of Xl6=1 , which we don't want.

Comment: in part 2, we want RHS to be greater than C, not greater than 0.